# Reading Celery task progress using AJAX polling

Tags: django, celery

I have a simple Celery task that write some progress data in the database. I need to read this progress update using a django view to give the update to the user.

I used my own tables to write the progress and read it using AJAX polling from client side. Now it's not working and I don't know the reason.

My database backend is PostgreSQL. I tried changing the transaction isolation level using the following (in the read view):

```
from django.db import transaction
#4 is READ UNCOMITTED
transaction.connections.all()[0].connection.set_isolation_level(4)
```

I am not sure if this changes the isolation level for a new connection to the database or the one the current transaction is using, but it doesn't seem to work. no progress data can be read until the task has finished and transaction is committed.

Here is second method I tried.

I also found [update_state](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.update_state), I write all the progress updates using `update_state`, but it doesn't seem to be actually written in the database. I run celerycam and configured celery to send events with -E argument.

I want to know what's the proper way to update progress day and retrieve it.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling I found out that "READ UNCOMMITTED" is not implemented in PostgreSQL and most probably won't be implemented in the future.

I also found an extension that allows you to read dirty data. It's part of project [enter link description here](https://github.com/omniti-labs/pgtreats), but this forced me to use raw sql to get the data I wanted.